# Discrepancy solving differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation: 
$$\frac{x \left(p'(x)+v'(x)\right)}{m+1}-v(x)=0$$
Solving for $v(x)$ using mathematica gives, 
$$v(x)=x^{m+1} \left(\int_1^x -y^{-m-1} p'(y) \, dy\right)+c_1 x^{m+1} \tag{1}$$
For a very specific case I know: 
$$v(x)=4 x + 46 x^2 + 382 x^3 + 958 x^4 + 1084 x^5 + 536 x^6 - 177 x^7 - 
 781 x^8 - 907 x^9 - 720 x^{10} - 290 x^{11} - 107 x^{12} - 24 x^{13} - 4 x^{14}\tag{2}$$
$$p(x)=2 x + 142 x^2 + 994 x^3 + 3068 x^4 + 5440 x^5 + 7516 x^6 + 8061 x^7 + 
 6591 x^8 + 4215 x^9 + 2029 x^{10} + 694 x^{11} + 181 x^{12} + 33 x^{13} + 
 4 x^{14}$$
hence, 
$$p'(y)=56 y^{13}+429 y^{12}+2172 y^{11}+7634 y^{10}+20290 y^9+37935 y^8+52728 y^7+56427 y^6+45096 y^5+27200 y^4+12272 y^3+2982 y^2+284 y+2$$ 
with m=26, and substituting this into (1) I get: 
$$v(x)=c_1 x^{27}-13607.5 x^{27}+4.30769 x^{14}+30.6429 x^{13}+144.8 x^{12}+477.125 x^{11}+1193.53 x^{10}+2107.5 x^9+2775.16 x^8+2821.35 x^7+2147.43 x^6+1236.36 x^5+533.565 x^4+124.25 x^3+11.36 x^2+0.0769231 x$$
Assume the first two terms are dropped I wonder why the the $v(x)$ I'm getting differs with the one in (2), am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this.

$$\frac{x \left(p'(x)+v'(x)\right)}{m+1}-v(x)=0$$

or

$$
\frac{x \left(p'(x)+v'(x)\right)}{m+1}-(p(x)+v(x))=-p(x)
$$

now calling $u(x) = p(x) + v(x)$ we have

$$
\frac{x}{m+1}u'(x)-u(x) = -p(x)
$$

with solution

$$
v(x) = x^{m+1} \left(c_1-(m+1)\int_1^x  \eta ^{-(m+2)} p(\eta ) \, d\eta \right)-p(x)
$$

Using

$$
m = 26,\ \ p(x)=2 x + 142 x^2 + 994 x^3 + 3068 x^4 + 5440 x^5 + 7516 x^6 + 8061 x^7 + 
 6591 x^8 + 4215 x^9 + 2029 x^{10} + 694 x^{11} + 181 x^{12} + 33 x^{13} + 
 4 x^{14}
$$

I obtained

$$
v(x) = \left(c_1-52577.5\right) x^{27}+4.30769 x^{14}+30.6429 x^{13}+144.8 x^{12}+477.125 x^{11}+1193.53 x^{10}+2107.5
   x^9+2775.16 x^8+2821.35 x^7+2147.43 x^6+1236.36 x^5+533.565 x^4+124.25 x^3+11.36 x^2+0.0769231 x
$$

almost the same as before. The only discrepancy is at the $x^{27}$ coefficient but there is involved the integration constant $c_1$ so it can be considered that this coefficient is $c_2 = c_1-52577.5$ and then the result is the same. The conclusion is that the guess about $v(x)$ was wrong.